# Which backup software use?

Tags: linux, backup

i have external hdd and i want two different backup policies:

- Identical backup of one folder to ext hdd, but only changed/create files will be writen every day
- Full backup another folder every day, but delete files like ./*/bin*, ./*/obj* in backups older than 1 week

Which backup software can you recommend to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interesting tool I've recently discovered is [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/).

```
rdiff-backup backs up one directory to another, possibly over a
network. The target directory ends up a copy of the source
directory, but extra reverse diffs are stored in a special
subdirectory of that target directory, so you can still recover
files lost some time ago. The idea is to combine the best
features of a mirror and an incremental backup. rdiff-backup also
preserves subdirectories, hard links, dev files, permissions,
uid/gid ownership, modification times, extended attributes, acls,
and resource forks. Also, rdiff-backup can operate in a bandwidth
efficient manner over a pipe, like rsync. Thus you can use
rdiff-backup and ssh to securely back a hard drive up to a remote
location, and only the differences will be transmitted. Finally,
rdiff-backup is easy to use and settings have sensical defaults.
```

Comment: This sounds good too

Comment: The good thing is that it stores all the incremental versions, just like `Subversion` does for the code.

Comment: I can't make choice between rdiff-backup and rsync

Comment: Is rdiff-backup supporting identical backup/copy/change/delete every day?

Comment: As far as I know (I use it from yesterday...) every rdiff-backup invocation updates the identical copy and adds a new diff to the list so you can also ask the version of the backup files of (say) three days ago. I find it very useful. I suggest you to take a look at the man for all the options. Here's some examples (http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/examples.html).

Answer (score 2):

None other than the fabulous [`rsync`](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) :)

Excluding filetypes from the backup is as simple as using 1 switch:

```
rsync -avz --exclude="*.obj" /home/john/critical john@superuser.com:/blah
```

Comment: and can you explain some example of doing things like i've posted

Comment: Example and man page has been provided

Comment: OK, you've answered the question, provide example isn't in question :). I'll ask for complete configuration in another question.